# User in added to the database but there is no way to login cakePHP2.6.0

Tags: cakephp, password-encryption

does any one can give me a hint why me login doesn't work?

It is possible to add a user, also the Blowfish password is created and the dataset in in saved into the database, but i can not login.

MODEL

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
App::uses('BlowfishPasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth');
class Benutzer extends AppModel{
 public $useTable = 'Benutzer';

 public $validate = array(
    'username' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => 'benötigtes Feld'
        )
    ),
    'passwort' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => 'benötigtes Feld'
        )
    ),
    'rolle' => array(
         'valid' => array(
            'rule' => array('inList', array('admin', 'author', 'borrow', 'archive')),
            'message' => 'Please enter a valid role',
            'allowEmpty' => false)
    )
);


    public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['passwort'])) {
        $passwordHasher = new BlowfishPasswordHasher();
        $this->data[$this->alias]['passwort'] = $passwordHasher->hash($this->data[$this->alias]['passwort']);
    }
    return true;
}
```

AppContorler

```
public $components = array(
                        'DebugKit.Toolbar',
                        'Session',
                        'Paginator' => array(
                            'className' => 'Bancha.BanchaPaginator'),
                        'Auth' => array(
                            'loginRedirect' => array(
                                'controller' => 'posts',
                                'action' => 'index'
                            ),
                            'logoutRedirect' => array(
                                'controller' => 'pages',
                                'action' => 'display',
                                'home'
                            ),
                            'authenticate' => array(
                                'Form' => array(
                                    'passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish'
                                    )
                            ),
                       )
                   );

    public function beforeFilter() {
      $this->Auth->allow('index', 'view');
  }
```

the login

```
public function login() {

            if ($this->request->is('post')) {
                if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                    return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
                }
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
            }

        }
```

LOGIN ctp-File

```
<div class="users form">
<?php echo $this->Session->flash('auth'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Benutzer'); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>
            <?php echo __('Please enter your username and password'); ?>
        </legend>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('username', array('lable' => 'Username', 'type' => 'text'));?>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('passwort', array('lable' => 'Passwort', 'type' => 'password'));?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Login')); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the field type & length for password in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that i haven't define the 'fields'

```
 'authenticate' => array(
      'Form' => array(
      'fields' => array(
      'username' => 'username', //Default is 'username' in the userModel
      'password' => 'passwort'  //Default is 'password' in the userModel
      )
```